# form Entity ordered by translated value

Tags: symfony

I have an entity category, which has a code. This code is internal, and we use translate it for each language. for exemple, imagine this:

```
Categories:
---- id:1 Code: "Bread"
---- id:2 Code: "Butter"
```

I have a form with a form field entity. I want to order it by translated label.

In English for exemple, it will display

```
Bread
Butter
```

But in french for exemple, the order is different

```
Beurre (butter)
Pain (bread)
```

So I can't use the orderBy of the entity field.

I have a hand-made solution, **very dirty**: I use an choice field with translated label

```
$categories_translated =array();
$categories= $this->em->getRepository('MyRepo')->findAll();
foreach($categories as $category){
    $categories_translated[$category->getId()]= $this->translator->trans($category);
}
asort($categories_translated);//sorted 

//then later
$builder->add('category','choice',array( 'choices' => $choices_technologies) )
```

Do you have a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is the best (and I think the only) way to handle this issue with file based translations. There are indeed more possibilities to address problems like this with database related translations. For example: https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md

Answer (score 0):

Are the codes static? i.e. the oven-baked dough (whatever language) is always id=1 in your data dictionaries, then the sorting is fine.
Hypothetically, if you had a table as follows:

```
category
    - catid int auto_increment,
    - locale varchar(5),
    - itemid int,
    - text varchar(100)
```

One can do select to access to categories sorted by `text`.
If one just rasterises according to the relevant locale and wanted items, you get global ids for your categories.

You may wish to use a better i18n mechanism, but this would be very simple for static categories.

Comment: It seems like it needs more code/db_request after the form submit to bind the category translated to the reference category.
Because if an english choose butter and the French choose Beurre, I want the two of them linked to the same database entity

Comment: Both of these would be the same `itemid`.  If you needed more properties attached to the category than its "englishification" (Perl term), then this would be stored in an extra entity.